# Getting error that event handler not registered in Coldbox

Tags: coldfusion, event-handling, coldbox

I am getting the following error message. I have already created Uploads.cfc handler in handlers directory. Checked everything, can't find the solution.

> Error Type: HandlerService.EventHandlerNotRegisteredException : [N/A]
>
> Error Messages: The event: uploads is not valid registered event.

Here is the Uploads.cfc code:

```
<!--- Default Action --->
<cffunction name="index" returntype="string" output="false" hint="My main event">
    <cfargument name="event">
    <cfargument name="rc">
    <cfargument name="prc">  
    
    <cfobject component="model.Uploader" name="fileUploader">
    <cfset filesJson = fileUploader.Upload(rc.file)>
    
    <cfreturn filesJson>
</cffunction>
```

Can you please suggest a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have also encountered the same problem in the past. Try restart the ColdFusion Application Server.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't have to restart the whole CF server. You just need to re-initialize ColdBox. Just add `?fwreint=` or `?fwreint={password}` to the URL. The password is set in `ColdBox.cfc`: "reinitpassword". You can also configure in `ColdBox.cfc` to not cache handlers in non-production environments.

If you're using ColdBox 3.6 or newer, you don't have to define `event, rc and prc` anymore.

```
<cffunction name="index" returntype="string" output="false" hint="My main event">
    <cfobject component="model.Uploader" name="fileUploader">
    <cfset filesJson = fileUploader.Upload(rc.file)>
    <cfreturn filesJson>
</cffunction>
```

Secondly, you should use [WireBox](http://wiki.coldbox.org/wiki/WireBox.cfm) instead of creating objects on the fly as you're doing. And finally, don't define variables specific to a function into the `variables` scope of the handler CFC file. Prefix them with `local` to make sure that those variables are "function local": only available to the particular function that is using them.

```
<cffunction name="index" returntype="string" output="false" hint="My main event">
    <cfset local.fileUploader = getModel("Uploader") >
    <cfset local.filesJson = fileUploader.Upload(rc.file)>
    <cfreturn local.filesJson>
</cffunction>
```

Comment: It depends on your settings in ColdBox.cfc. If you have a password set, then it's reinit={password}. If no password, then just reinit=.

Answer (score 0):

iKnowKungFu misspelled ?fwreint= (missing i)
Should be ?fwreinit

Comment: I wish I had posted this.  Heh.